# Attaching maps in CW Complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can anybody make me understand the $attaching$ $map$ in CW Complexes? I need mathematical definition of it? Is it really a function? Any fruitful links containing the definition of attaching maps please.

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space).

Comment: They are attaching spaces, I'm interested in attaching maps.

Comment: @PrinceThomas  did you read the link?

Comment: My book "Topology and Groupoids" (do a web search) has over 10 pages on adjunction spaces and their properties. The term "attaching map" is not used, but the description of finite cell complexes in Section 4.7 should help sort this out.

Comment: When you form an adjunction space $B \cup_f X$ where $A$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and $f: A \to B$, then $f$ is often called the **attaching map**.

Comment: This book mentioned by @RonnieBrown is indeed a very nice book on this subject  (and more). I red it for a big part and learned a lot.